# How can I associate a file type in mac within Java code?

Tags: java

How can I associate a file type like .vlan in mac within java code?

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSHandlers -array-add 
\"<dict><key>LSHandlerContentTag</key>
<string>.vlan</string><key>LSHandlerContentTagClass</key>
<string>public.filename-extension</string><key>LSHandlerRoleAll</key>
<string>org.category.program</string></dict>\"");
```

Comment: Huh? Could you rephrase that in the form of a question? Associate it with what?

Comment: Well, my application is supposed to be crossed platform so I already went through the ftype and assoc commands to cover the Windows part of things and it works great, however, now I need to cover the same file type for mac.  Please keep in mind that my understanding of the mac environment is very limited

Comment: Duplicate, answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2976711/493928)

Comment: But that answer is not in regards to Java.  I'm looking for a solution from within Java.

Comment: @Sam `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("...");`. I think you should search a little before asking.

Comment: You mean something like what I put in the question area will work in mac?

Answer (score 1):

If the app. has a GUI, deploy it using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) and declare the file extension/type in the JNLP (launch) file.  Here is a [demo. of the JNLP API file services](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs) which should be able to associate the `text/sleepytime` content type of `.zzz` file with the (small) app.

Adding an association for a file type is supported to work on Windows, OS X **&** *nix (for all permissions, as well as sand-boxed apps. (the latter prompted)).

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
    new String[] {
        "defaults", 
        "write", 
        "com.apple.LaunchServices", 
        "LSHandlers", 
        "-array-add",   
        "<dict><key>LSHandlerContentTag</key><string>.vlan</string><key>LSHandlerContentTagClass</key><string>public.filename-extension</string><key>LSHandlerRoleAll</key><string>org.category.program</string></dict>"
    }
);
```

And just to add, Runtime's exec has [quite some pitfalls](http://www.javaworld.com/cgi-bin/mailto/x_java.cgi?pagetosend=/export/home/httpd/javaworld/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html&pagename=/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html&pageurl=http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html&site=jw_core) one need to be aware of.