# Is there a way to associate a filetype to my PyInstaller build wxPython app?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, wxpython, pyinstaller

I have written a desktop application in Python and wxPython, which I am in the process of finetuning.
One of the things I want it to be able to do is open on double clicking on specific files (e.g. `*.m4baker`)

I build it into an `M4Baker.app` with PyInstaller. That all goes fine but how can I associate a file type to my macOS app?

Note that I am not searching on how to associate the file type after creation but (programmatically / during install?!)

For those interested here is the complete codebase: http://ivo2u.nl/ZR

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: hey Ivo have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969987/macosx-file-extension-associate-with-application-programmatically/2976711#2976711

Comment: You can also use cli commands inside your python script.