# Mac: How to assign a file extension to be opened with my java .app application?

Tags: java, macos

I have created a Java application and created a Mac .app file from it to run simply on Mac OS X. The application can create special project files and save them with the extension *.ksdi so the user can easily run those project files again and edit them.

What I would like to do is allow the user who installed the application on his Mac to be able to double click those *.ksdi files to automatically run the program and automatically load the project file. How can I do that in Mac?

Can I assign an extension to my Mac program through a script or something like that so user won't have to assign the extension to the program manually?

**Update: Trial solution:**

I have read in another post that I should add a key to the *.plist file to accomplish this, so I added this to it:

```
<plist>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
                <string>Viewer</string>

                <key>LSIsAppleDefaultForType</key>
                <true/>

                <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
                <array>
                    <string>public.ksdi</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

I saved the plist file, but I do not know how to activate this!
I have run the application, restarted my mac, but still when double clicking any ksdi file it doesn't open it with the program... Any help?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575190/double-click-document-file-in-mac-os-x-to-open-java-application

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to associate file type with MacOS X App without launching it first?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435175/how-to-associate-file-type-with-macos-x-app-without-launching-it-first)

Comment: Thanks guys, but those questions have no clear answers. Should i add a property to the *.plist file to accomplish this or what ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to associate file type with MacOS X App without launching it first?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435175/how-to-associate-file-type-with-macos-x-app-without-launching-it-first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per one of the "[exact duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435175/how-to-associate-file-type-with-macos-x-app-without-launching-it-first)" questions.

[Application Registration](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCConcepts/LSCConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000999-CH202-TP9)

> All applications available on the user’s system must be registered to
>   make them known to Launch Services and copy their document binding and
>   other information into its database. It isn’t ordinarily necessary to
>   perform this task explicitly, since a variety of utilities and
>   services built into the Mac OS X system software take care of it
>   automatically:
>
> A built-in background tool, run whenever the system is booted or a new
>   user logs in, automatically searches the Applications folders in the
>   system, network, local, and user domains and registers any new
>   applications it finds there. (This operation is analogous to
>   “rebuilding the desktop” in earlier versions of Mac OS.) The Finder
>   automatically registers all applications as it becomes aware of them,
>   such as when they are dragged onto the user’s disk or when the user
>   navigates to a folder containing them. When the user attempts to open
>   a document for which no preferred application can be found in the
>   Launch Services database, the Finder presents a dialog asking the user
>   to select an application with which to open the document. It then
>   registers that application before launching it.
>
> In spite of these automatic registration utilities, it may sometimes
>   be necessary to register an application explicitly with Launch
>   Services. For example, although developers are encouraged to package
>   their applications so that they can be installed by simply dragging
>   them onto the user’s disk, some applications may require more
>   elaborate custom installer software. In such cases, the installer
>   should call one of the Launch Services registration functions
>   LSRegisterFSRef or LSRegisterURL to register the application
>   explicitly.

Comment: How can i register my application as mentioned in 1st line ? I don't want to use an installer, so can i register my application + Use the plist keys specified in my question, and things will work fine ?

Comment: read for comprehension ALL the instructions in the **link** provided in my answer

Answer (score 2):

I do this using [Install4J](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html), they make it really easy.

(btw, I have no affiliation with Install4j or the company).

Comment: One note, I output to dmg, they may support .app, I'm not sure.