# Cocoa protocol handler using NSAppleEventManager and kInternetEventClass/kAEGetURL

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, url, protocols, handler

This is the Cocoa version of this question:

[AEInstallEventHandler handler not being called on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265487/aeinstalleventhandler-handler-not-being-called-on-startup)

Here's my Info.plist protocol registration:

```
    ...
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>My Protocol</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLIconFile</key>
            <string>myicon</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>myapp</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

Here's where I set the method to listen for the kInternetEventClass/kAEGetURL event when a browser link is clicked with the link "myapp://unused/?a=123&b=456":

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [[NSAppleEventManager sharedAppleEventManager] setEventHandler:self andSelector:@selector(getURL:withReplyEvent:) forEventClass:kInternetEventClass andEventID:kAEGetURL];
    ...
}
```

Here's the handler method:

```
- (void)getURL:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)event withReplyEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)reply
{
    [[[event paramDescriptorForKeyword:keyDirectObject] stringValue] writeToFile:@"/testbed/complete_url.txt" atomically:YES];
}
```

Here's the test web link:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="myapp://open/?a=123&b=456">Open My App</a>
</body>
</html>
```

This all works great if the application is already running.

The handler method is called and the complete url is captured.

However, if the app is not yet running the same link will launch the app, but the handler will not be invoked — which makes sense since the handler had not yet been bound to the event.

Those arguments in the URL are important for our application to coordinate with the webapp.  Although the vast majority of the time our application will already be running when this click occurs, it is reasonable to expect that in some cases it will not.

I've tried inspecting the environment and process invocation arguments and I do not see the URL in either of them.

Anyone know how we can capture this URL reliably, even when our application isn't already running when the browser click happens?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @canhazbits: Registering the handler in `-applicationWillFinishLaunching:` works in my testing. Is there something unusual in how this app is setup or configured? For example, could it be that the app delegate is not set or not the class you think it is? Or could it be set after the app has finished launching? Are you trying to do a NIB-less app? If you put log statements in `-applicationWillFinishLaunching:` and `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:`, are they both executed?

Comment: Yes, they are both executed. But no, putting the registration in `applicationWillFinishLaunching` does not work for me.

Comment: @canhazbits: What exactly is the failure mode? Is your handler method (`-getURL:withReplyEvent:` in the original question) being called? Is the event argument not what you expect? Is your case like the original in that the handler is called if the app is already running when the URL is opened? What do you get if you log `[[NSAppleEventManager sharedAppleEventManager] currentAppleEvent]` during `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` in the case where your app is launched by the URL opening?

Comment: @canhazbits [Chrome](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/chromium/+/master/chrome/browser/app_controller_mac.mm) registers in `awakeFromNib`. [Firefox](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/xre/MacApplicationDelegate.mm) registers in `init`. If neither works for you, your problem may be elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

Apple’s *SimpleScriptingPlugin* sample registers the handler in `applicationWillFinishLaunching:`, which is probably cleaner than using `init`. (And like mikker said, the handler gets called before `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`.)

Comment: I have tried in applicationWillFinishLaunching, applicationDidFinishLaunching and init method, but nothing worked out. Is there any other solution? It will be very helpful for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I just faced this exact problem. I don't know if it's the proper solution but you can register the event handler in the app delegate's `init`-method instead.

```
// in AppDelegate.m

- (id)init
{
  self = [super init];

  if (self) {
    [[NSAppleEventManager sharedAppleEventManager] setEventHandler:self andSelector:@selector(handleURLEvent:withReplyEvent:) forEventClass:kInternetEventClass andEventID:kAEGetURL];
  }

  return self;
}
```

One thing to note though is that `handleURLEvent:withReplyEvent` get's called *before* `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` if the app is started by an URL Scheme.

Comment: I have tried in applicationWillFinishLaunching, applicationDidFinishLaunching and init method, but nothing worked out. Is there any other solution? It will be very helpful for me. Thanks in advance.