# Associating a file extension with my application

Tags: macos, file-extension

I know how to manually associate a specific file or generic extension with a particular OS X application. *(Get Info > Open with > Other…)*

I know how, in OS X, to drag-and-drop a file with an extension onto an 'unsupported' application. *(Hold down command-option when dragging over the application)*

As the author of an OS X application, how can I specify that my application knows how to open a particular file extension?

- I want my users not to need to use command-option for drag-and-drop.
- I want my users to see my application listed under "Recommended Applications" instead of "All Applications" when picking an app to open my extensions.
- Ideally, I want my users to see files with my (unique, not-already-associated) extension magically show the correct icon and open with my application as soon as the `.app` is dragged into the Applications folder.

---

I have seen *["MacOSX - File extension associate with application - Programatically"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969987/macosx-file-extension-associate-with-application-programatically)*, but I do not want to have to have users run an installer or shell script after installation.

Comment: I only really care about the current and previous OS releases, so Mavericks and Mountain Lion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to associate file type with MacOS X App without launching it first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435175/how-to-associate-file-type-with-macos-x-app-without-launching-it-first)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To declare its support for file types, your app must include the [CFBundleDocumentTypes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-101685) key in its Info.plist

Then implement

[- application:openFile:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSApplicationDelegate/application%3aopenFile%3a) (for single file drag-drop)
or
- application:openFiles: (multiple files drag-drop)

Have a look at Complete the Information Property List section in [Document-Based App Programming Guide for Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/ApplicationCreationProcess/ApplicationCreationProcess.html)

Comment: Thank you. Searching the web was returning too many hits about user-based file associations for me to find the appropriate developer docs. this is exactly what I needed.