# Handling Mac OS X file open event BEFORE C++ main() executes

Tags: c++, macos, qt, events, qt5

I've googled a lot, but still unable to find nice solution :/
So, i'm porting one complicated Qt5 application (client of some network service) to Mac OS X (10.7.0 "Lion" and higher).

I need to handle custom file like `*.xyz` and custom URL scheme like `xyz://`.
Okay, Qt5 has the `QFileOpenEvent` class to handle OS X appropriate event.
**BUT**: this event arrives only after the application event loop starts (obviously)!

And i need to "catch" and handle OS X' file open event **BEFORE** `main` starts, because the program logic was designed to take care of the command line argument handling only.

The simplified `main` function code:

```
int main(int argc, char[]* argv)
{
     QApplication app( argc, argv );

     QStringList arguments = app.arguments();
     if( arguments.count() == argc ) arguments.removeFirst();

     Logic appLogic( NULL, &app );
     app.installMessageHandler( &appLogic );

     // The problem:
     // **This function will always called earlier than the any event**
     if( ! appLogic.start( arguments ) ) return 0;

     // Start processing of events
     // Only after this call Logic class get the desired event
     return app.exec();
}
```

Is there a way to get an OS X' file opening event **before** the C++ `main` function starts, or to get "my" file/url in the `argv` parameter?
Maybe, some `Objective-C` black magic does the job?

NOTE: `start` does many complicated - and asynchronous - things. Event arrives during it's execution, so it's hard to handle it when the async stuff is already working. So looks like i just need to prevent `start` execution, if the event will arrive.

If the application is already opened, there is no problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found one, propably weird, solution - use Qt' event system.

```
int main(int argc, char[]* argv)
{
    QApplication app( argc, argv );

    QStringList arguments = app.arguments();
    if( arguments.count() == argc ) arguments.removeFirst();

    Logic appLogic( NULL, &app );
    #ifdef Q_OS_MAC
    app.installMessageHandler( &appLogic );

    // Here we should alreasy get FileOpenEvent, if it occurs
    // NOTE: without this FileOpenEvent will arrive LATER
    //       than the DryRunEvent!
    app.processEvents();

    // If there is no file open event in the queue,
    // we should just open the blank program window
    // NOTE: Qt takes ownership of this event object,
    //       so you should not delete it manually
    DryRunEvent* runEv = new DryRunEvent( p );
    a.postEvent( &l, runEv, Qt::LowEventPriority );
    #endif

    ...

    #ifndef Q_OS_MAC
    if( ! appLogic.start( arguments ) ) return 0;
    #endif

    return app.exec();
}
```

Custom event header:

```
class BaseEvent : public QEvent
{
public:
    BaseEvent( QEvent::Type& eType ) : QEvent( getEventType( eType ) )
    {
    }

    ~BaseEvent() {}

    QEvent::Type getEventType( QEvent::Type& eType )
    {
        if( eType == QEvent::None )
        {
            eType = static_cast<QEvent::Type>( QEvent::registerEventType() );
        }
        return eType;
    }
};

class DryRunEvent : public BaseEvent
{
    QStringList m_params;

    public:
         DryRunEvent( const Parameters& params ) :
             BaseEvent( eventType ), m_params( params )
         {
         }

         ~DryRunEvent(){}

         QStringList GetCmdLineParams() const { return m_params; }

    public:
        static QEvent::Type eventType;
};
```

Custom event source:

```
QEvent::Type ViewerDryRunEvent::eventType = QEvent::None;
```

Logic class header:

```
class Logic : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_DISABLE_COPY( Logic )

    public:
        explicit Logic(QObject *parent, QApplication* application);
        virtual ~Logic();

    public slots:
        bool Start( QStringList parameters );
        void ReceiveParameters( QStringList parameters );
        void Stop();

        #ifdef Q_OS_MAC
        bool Logic::WasStarted() const
        {
            ... Determine wether logic was started or not ...
        }
        #endif

    private:
        #ifdef OS_MACOSX
        // Virtual overrided functions
         bool eventFilter( QObject* obj, QEvent* event )
         {
             if( event->type() == QEvent::FileOpen )
             {
                 QFileOpenEvent* fileEvent = static_cast< QFileOpenEvent* >(event);
                 Q_ASSERT( fileEvent != NULL );

                 QString uri;
                 if( fileEvent->file().isEmpty() == false )
                 {
                     uri = fileEvent->file();
                 }
                 else if( fileEvent->url().isEmpty() == false )
                 {
                     uri = fileEvent->url().toString();
                 }

                 if( uri.isEmpty() == false )
                 {
                     if( WasStarted() ) ReceiveParameters( uri );
                     else Start( uri );
                 }

                 return false;
             }
             else if( event->type() == DryRunEvent::eventType )
             {
                 DryRunEvent* myEvent = static_cast< DryRunEvent* >( event );
                 Q_ASSERT( myEvent != NULL );
                 QStringList cmdLineParams = myEvent->GetCmdLineParams();

                 Q_ASSERT( !WasStarted() );
                 if( WasStarted() ) return false;

                 if( !Start( cmdLineParams ) ) m_application->exit( 0 );
                 return false;
             }

             // Standard event processing
             return QObject::eventFilter( obj, event );
        }
        #endif
    };
```

I hope someone find this stuff useful :)